# Why does my interstitial ad show at the wrong time (but in the right place)?

Tags: android, admob, interstitial

I'd like to show an interstitial ad while going from MainActivity to Activity2.  Instead, the ad only shows when clicking back from Activity2 to the MainActivity.

Does anyone know what I've done wrong?

Thanks

I have a button in MainActivity that loads Activity2.  I have the following in the code for the button.

```
 if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
            mInterstitialAd.show(MainActivity.this);
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Ad failed to load");

    }
```

I thought I could solve the problem by replacing MainActivity.this with Activity2, but it get a red underline.  I've tried "Activity2," "Activity2.class" and "Activity2.java."

The below code is for loading and calling the ads.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
            }
        });
        loadInterstitial();



    public void loadInterstitial(){
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        InterstitialAd.load(this, getString(R.string.interstitial_ad_unit_id), adRequest, new             InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
                super.onAdLoaded(interstitialAd);
                Log.d(TAG, "Ad loaded successfully");
                mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd;
                mInterstitialAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(new FullScreenContentCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(@NonNull AdError adError) {
                        super.onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(adError);
                        Log.d(TAG, "Ad failed to show");

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
                        super.onAdShowedFullScreenContent();
                        Log.d(TAG, "Ad shown successfully");
                        mInterstitialAd = null;

                    }


                    @Override
                    public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                        super.onAdDismissedFullScreenContent();
                        Log.d(TAG, "Ad dismissed");
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                super.onAdFailedToLoad(loadAdError);
                Log.i(TAG, "onAdLoaded");
                mInterstitialAd = null;
            }
        });

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add changes like below way.

> In **MainActivity** to write below code

Add constant

```
public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;
```

Call Activity2 like below way

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                Activity2.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent , REQUEST_CODE);
```

Now use onActivityResult to retrieve the result

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        try {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE  && resultCode  == RESULT_OK) {

               loadInterstitial();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Toast.makeText(Activity.this, ex.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
```

> And **Activity2** to write below code whenever you are press back
> key/button action

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
intent.putExtra("key", value);
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

Comment: I don't have a back button in my program and use the system back button instead.  I wrote this in Activity2.  

public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
//        intent.putExtra("key", value);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
        return;
    }

I commented out intent.putExtra because I didn’t know which value I was transferring.

I got a red underline for “Activity.this”, so I changed it to MainActivity.this 

The ad still only shows when going back from Activity2 to MainActivity.